# How do I configure a proxy using ionic2?

Tags: proxy, ionic2

Ionic 2 has deprecated ionic.config.js.  ionic.project is now ionic.config.json, and I'm supposed to put my settings in there now.  So, following the instructions for ionic proxies for ionic (can't find ionic2 doc for this anywhere), my ionic.config.json now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "newapp",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "https://api.service.com"
  }]
}
```

But, this doesn't appear to work.

UPDATE:  I seem to be getting the proxied service, but I am still getting CORS errors.

Comment: read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763775/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-upon-ionic2-http-post-request/37779476#37779476, hope this help

Answer (score 6):

The issue I was having was with the server itself... it is not enough to restart it after changing the configuration.  The server must be quit and a new one started with `ionic serve` to behave correctly.

The above configuration, in `ionic.config.json` is the correct way to configure a proxy.