# Ionic 3 Error in JSON Parsing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, typescript, ionic-framework

In Ionic i am getting this error while trying to parse JSON data.

```
Error : Response with status: 0  for URL: null
```

I need to print the product name(Turmeric Powder) in the list format

JSON Response is

```
[{"product_id":"40","sku":"HOS001","name":"Turmeric Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","3"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"41","sku":"HOS001-20 grms","name":"Turmeric Powder-20 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]}}]
```

Type Script code:

```
  getdata(){

  this.loading.present();
  this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(

  result => {
            console.log('getJsonData completed');

    this.newsData=result.data.result;
    console.log("Success : "+this.newsData);
  },
  err =>{
    console.error("Error : "+err);
  } ,
  () => {
    this.loading.dismiss();
    console.log('getData completed');
  }
);
}
```

Provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
Generated class for the HttpProvider provider.

 See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
 for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
 */

 @Injectable()
 export class HttpProvider {

 constructor(public http: Http) {
 console.log('Hello HttpProvider Provider');
 }

 getJsonData(){
  return this.http.get('http://happyos.in/prd.php').map(res => res.json());
 }}
```

Comment: Are you running with `ionic serve`? This is likely a CORS issue

Comment: @suraj yes i am runnning this in firefox browser using ionic serve

Comment: @suraj can you please suggest how to resolve CORS issue

Comment: One way is https://stackoverflow.com/a/37779476/4826457

Comment: Thanks @suraj it was CORS issue as you said. But i resolve it by adding chrome extension "Allow control allow origin" in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for CORS issue by adding Google Chrome extension Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But before we have to enable it each time we open the browser